# Combine SimpleXMLRPCServer and BaseHTTPRequestHandler in Python

Tags: python, httpserver, simplexmlrpcserver

Because cross-domain xmlrpc requests are not possible in JavaScript
I need to create a Python app which exposes both some HTML through HTTP and an XML-RPC service on the same domain.

Creating an HTTP request handler and SimpleXMLRPCServer in python is quite easy,
but they both have to listen on a different port, which means a different domain.

Is there a way to create something that will listen on a single port on the localhost
and expose both the HTTPRequestHandler and XMLRPCRequest handler?

Right now I have two different services:

```
httpServer = HTTPServer(('localhost',8001), HttpHandler);
xmlRpcServer = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost',8000),requestHandler=RequestHandler)
```

**Update**

- I cannot install Apache on the device
- The hosted page will be a single html page
- The only client will be the device on witch the python service runs itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple, based on Wai Yip Tung's reply:

All I had to do was keep using the SimpleXMLRPCServer instance,
but modify the handler:

```
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

    def do_GET(self):
          #implementation here
```

This will cause the handler to respond to GET requests as well as the original POST (XML-RPC) requests.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them subclass of `SocketServer.TCPServer`. There must be someway to refactor them so that once server instance can dispatch to both.

An easier alternative may be to keep the `HTTPServer` in front and proxy XML RPC to the  `SimpleXMLRPCServer` instance.

Comment: This has helped me find my solutions

Answer (score 0):

Using `HTTPServer` for providing contents is not a good idea. You should use a webserver like Apache and use Python as CGI (or a more advanced interface like `mod_wsgi`).

Then, the webserver is running on one port and you can server HTML directly over the webserver  and write as many CGI scripts as you like in Python, as example one for XMLRPC requests using `CGIXMLRPCRequestHandler`.

```
class MyFuncs:
    def div(self, x, y) : return x // y


handler = CGIXMLRPCRequestHandler()
handler.register_function(pow)
handler.register_function(lambda x,y: x+y, 'add')
handler.register_introspection_functions()
handler.register_instance(MyFuncs())
handler.handle_request()
```

Comment: Problem is I cannot install apache on the target device (being a restricted apple device :p)